# LinearLayout fading effect contents

Tags: android, view, effect, fading

So, in my current project I have a LinearLayout with orientation set to vertical. During runtime, views will be added to the Layout programatically. I would like the contents of the layout to fade out (trail off) at the bottom instead of just being cut off. I've looked into fadingEdge but no matter how I change the settings for fadingEdge and fadingEdgeLength, there appears to be no change in how the view looks.

Info:

- Working in Eclipse layout editor
- Using a custom theme (HoloEverywhere)
- Target is 4.0.3 but minSdkVersion is 8 (im using android compatibility and sherlockactivitybar)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the LinearLayout the root of your content?  If so, you might try wrapping it in a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as the method was deprecated at the release of ICS, and that it's now ignored (at least that's what the documentation says)...